# How can I get create-react-app to use an IP to connect to my api server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, create-react-app, koa

I'm using Facebook's create-react-app. When I start the web-client I see in console:

```
You can now view web-client in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.107:3000/
```

The problem is my web-client uses localhost to connect to the api-server, which means I can't use the IP address on different devices to debug issues.

**env-variables.js:**

```
export const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const ALL_ENV_VARS = {
  development: {
    GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URI: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  },
....
```

I tried updating the above with:

```
GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URI: `http://${process.env.ip}:4000/graphql`,
```

That did not work, `process.env.ip` is returning undefined. How can I get the above GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URI to use the IP address which somehow create-react-app is getting?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your client-side package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/",
```

You can then leave the

```
http://localhost:4000
```

off of any URLs pointing to the API server from the client side.  You would just refer to those addresses as

```
/graphql/<any additional URL data>
```

I've performed the same with a Node/Express backend and a React frontend - I resolved the /api portion in my server.js with the following:

```
//Use our router configuration when we call /api
app.use('/api', router);
```

just replace /api with /graphql there.

Take a look at this article for further explanation.  Hope this helps!

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works with `react-scripts v5.0.1` in a non-ejected `create-react-app` project:

Modify `script.start` in `package.json`:

```json
"scripts: {
   "start": "LOCAL_LAN_IP=$(node -e \"console.log(require('address').ip())\") react-scripts start",
   // other scripts...
}
```

then create a `.env` file in your root, add the following:

```bash
REACT_APP_LOCAL_LAN_IP=$LOCAL_LAN_IP
```

Your local IP should become available in your react app in **`process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_LAN_IP`**, whenever you start the app with `npm start`.

##### How does it work?

By prepending the `react-scripts start` command that is executed when we run `npm start` with:

```bash
LOCAL_LAN_IP=$(node -e \"console.log(require('address').ip())\")
```

1. we invoke `node` to execute `require('address').ip()`
2. we `console.log` the value returned from ip()
3. the `console.log` prints to `STDOUT`
4. we then catch `STDOUT` with bash's command substitution `$()`
5. the string caught from `STDOUT` will be assigned to the variable `LOCAL_LAN_IP`
6. which we then expand in our `.env` file and assign it to `REACT_APP_LOCAL_LAN_IP`.

**Notes:**

- `REACT_APP_` prefix is needed to make it available in the `process.env` in the app's code's context.
- `address` package should already be installed, as it is a peer dependency of `react-scripts@5.0.1`. It is used in the `react-scripts start` command to print the local ip, which we see in the OP.